# AttributeError: module 'pystan' has no attribute 'StanModel'

Tags: python, pip, pystan

After running the following line (already exist the package):

```
pip install -vvv pystan

Requirement already satisfied: pystan in /Users/cmougan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.17.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython!=0.25.1,>=0.22 in /Users/cmougan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pystan) (0.28.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in /Users/cmougan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pystan) (1.16.2)
Carloss-MacBook-Pro:Desktop cmougan$ pip install -vvv pystan
Non-user install because site-packages writeable
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/j6/tcx3t7vj4fs8rsb97cwg06nc0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-0p2f3viv
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/j6/tcx3t7vj4fs8rsb97cwg06nc0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-lg301zxr
Initialized build tracking at /private/var/folders/j6/tcx3t7vj4fs8rsb97cwg06nc0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-lg301zxr
Created build tracker: /private/var/folders/j6/tcx3t7vj4fs8rsb97cwg06nc0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-lg301zxr
Entered build tracker: /private/var/folders/j6/tcx3t7vj4fs8rsb97cwg06nc0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-lg301zxr
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/j6/tcx3t7vj4fs8rsb97cwg06nc0000gn/T/pip-install-8ffjd5t4
Requirement already satisfied: pystan in /Users/cmougan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.17.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython!=0.25.1,>=0.22 in /Users/cmougan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pystan) (0.28.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in /Users/cmougan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pystan) (1.16.2)
Removed build tracker: '/private/var/folders/j6/tcx3t7vj4fs8rsb97cwg06nc0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-lg301zxr'
```

I perform the following:

```py
import pystan
model_code = 'parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(0,1);}'
model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=model_code)  # this will take a minute
y = model.sampling(n_jobs=1).extract()['y']
y.mean()  # should be close to 0
```

And I get the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-d7f147a8ee3e> in <module>
      1 import pystan
      2 model_code = 'parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(0,1);}'
----> 3 model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=model_code)  # this will take a minute
      4 y = model.sampling(n_jobs=1).extract()['y']
      5 y.mean()  # should be close to 0

AttributeError: module 'pystan' has no attribute 'StanModel'
```

I am using python 3.6 and pip. I am using the flag -vvv for more verbose to help in the debugging of the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a file `pystan.py` lying around. `import pystan` imports from the file instead of the installed `pystan` package.

Remove or rename the file. And never create files `.py` that shadows existing modules like `email.py`, `test.py`, etc.

Comment: Thxs! I can not find any pystan.py file lying around.